# Getting Warning in Spring boot application While doing Gradle Clean build

Tags: gradle

When I doing GRADLE CLEAN BUILD.

I suddenly started getting this warning. How can I resolve it

```
**WARNING - Property with name 'project_type' is missing in your configuration. Assuming SPRING_BOOT_APPLICATION. Consider declaring such a property to explictly define the type of your project. Supported values are:
  for SPRING_BOOT_APPLICATION : ['SPRING_BOOT_APPLICATION']
  for GRADLE_PLUGIN : ['GRADLE_PLUGIN']
  for JAVA_LIBRARY : ['JAVA_LIBRARY']**
```

Comment: which version of the SpringBoot plugin and which version of Gradle are you using?  what is the list of plugins applied to your build script?

Comment: $ gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.12
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2016-03-14 08:32:03 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     b29fbb64ad6b068cb3f05f7e40dc670472129bc0

Groovy:       2.4.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.8.0_121 (Oracle Corporation 25.121-b31)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64

Comment: spring-boot-gradle-plugin with 1.5.11.RELEASE version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is custom plugin message, not a message which comes from Gradle. It is probably a plugin which you use in your organization. Try to search for the message in your local repos.

PS. **explicitly** is misspelled.

Comment: Thanks for info. After much research, I found same.